# vb 2010 conditional statements inside listview

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I put three items in a listview and checkboxes to choose one of them at time. The code works if I check the items from the first to the last but it doesn't when and go backwards. I mean, after choosing the last item if I choose again the second the message shown is wrong. How can fix it?

Cheers.

```
    For Each Me.item In lsv_school.Items
        If Not item.Index = e.Index Then
            item.Checked = False
            If e.Index = lsv_school.Items(0).Checked Then
                lbl_err.Hide()
                lbl_feed.Text = "Your school tuition will be " + "$" & dipAcc + " per term."
            ElseIf e.Index = lsv_school.Items(1).Checked Then
                lbl_err.Hide()
                lbl_feed.Text = "Your school tuition will be " + "$" & dipBus + " per term."
            ElseIf e.NewValue = lsv_school.Items(2).Checked Then
                lbl_err.Hide()
                lbl_feed.Text = "Your school tuition will be " + "$" & dipMar + " per term."
            End If
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: The code makes completely no sense, impossible to guess what it is supposed to do.  At least put Option Strict On at the top of the source code file to catch the biggest mistakes.

Comment: What I want my code to do is to check one item at time in a listview object and once one of the three choices is checked display a text message of the selection. I know that the code is messy but it actually works. If you know a better way, please, suggest it to me.

Comment: If it works then why are you asking this question?  Use RadioButtons instead, they were made for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the mess by myself, thanks for your suggestions but I had to use those components and could not do otherwise. I will post the code I used.

The first sub class is a loop to check one checkbox at time.

```
Private Sub lsv_school_ItemCheck(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.ItemCheckEventArgs) Handles lsv_school.ItemCheck

        'Loop to check one checkbox at time.
        For Each Me.item In lsv_school.Items

            If Not item.Index = e.Index Then
                item.Checked = False
            End If

        Next

    End Sub
```

The second sub class solve the problem, the conditional statements now check each case properly.

```
Private Sub lsv_school_ItemChecked(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As ItemCheckedEventArgs) Handles lsv_school.ItemChecked

    'Conditional statements to select one course at time.
    If lsv_school.Items(0).Checked = True Then
        item.Selected = CBool(dipAcc)
        lbl_err.Hide()
        lbl_feed.Show()
        lbl_feed.Text = "Your school tuition will be " + "$" & dipAcc
    ElseIf lsv_school.Items(1).Checked = True Then
        item.Selected = CBool(dipBus)
        lbl_err.Hide()
        lbl_feed.Show()
        lbl_feed.Text = "Your school tuition will be " + "$" & dipBus
    ElseIf lsv_school.Items(2).Checked = True Then
        item.Selected = CBool(dipMar)
        lbl_err.Hide()
        lbl_feed.Show()
        lbl_feed.Text = "Your school tuition will be " + "$" & dipMar
    Else
        If item.Checked = False Then
            lbl_feed.Text = ""
            lbl_feed.Hide()
            lbl_err.Show()
            lbl_err.Text = "Select a course from the list."
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

In this way I managed to let checkboxes work as radiobuttons inside a listview.